# ¿El andaluz es una lengua como el catalán?

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos

He tenido preguntas sobre que si el andaluz es un idioma como el catalán o el euskera, porque se nota un poco la diferencia del habla, es decir, la pronunciación  entre el castellano y andaluz.

Comment: [*Una lengua es un dialecto con un ejército y una marina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Una_lengua_es_un_dialecto_con_un_ej%C3%A9rcito_y_una_marina)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El andaluz es más bien un dialecto, o sea es una variedad del español que se habla en el sur del país, Andalucía. Tienes razón con lo de que se parecen mucho pero tiene características como el seseo por ejemplo que lo diferencian del castellano.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias User!

Comment: En el norte? Es lo opuesto, al sur.

Comment: Si, cierto perdón, estaba pensando en Cataluña. Qué error más tonto

Answer (score 3):

Aunque, como indica @Random_User en su respuesta, el andaluz es un [**dialecto**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialecto_andaluz), no faltan personas e instituciones que lo consideran una lengua.

Por ejemplo:

- [aquí](https://andalu.fandom.com/wiki/Lengua_andaluza/B) se recoge:

> El andalú (tamién yamáo **lengua andalusa o idioma andalú**) ë el idioma qe se paula en Andalusía, ener sú d'Ëpanha. Anqe sufre bariasionë heográficä, lö paulantë d'ëte idioma poseen muxä caräterîtikcä en común. El orihen del andalú debemö bücallo en la época andalusí, en la cuá er latín burgá paulao en Al-Andalus ebolusionó äta la lengua d'alyamía, la paulá pol lö abitantë d'Al-Andalus no relasionaö con lä élitë dominantë (lä cualë paulabán árabe o berebé)...

- el [**Andaluh transcriptor**](https://andaluh.es/transcriptor/#/) "*traduce*" palabras y textos del *câtteyano* al *andalûh*. Según este transcriptor, la pregunta del OP:

> "He tenido preguntas sobre que si el andaluz es un idioma como el catalán o el euskera, porque se nota un poco la diferencia del habla, es decir, la pronunciación entre el castellano y andaluz."
>
> pasaría a ser:
>
> "E tenío preguntâ çobre que çi el andalûh êh un idioma como er catalán o el eûkkera, porque çe nota un poco la diferençia del abla, êh deçîh, la pronunçiaçión entre er câtteyano y andalûh."